# webpack resolve path to entrypoint

Tags: javascript, webpack, ecmascript-6

I have a webpack project with two entrypoints:

```js
module.exports = {
  entry: {
    main: ["src/main.js"],
    worker: ["src/worker.js"],
  },
  output: {
    path: 'dist',
    filename: '[name].[chunkhash:6].js',
  }
};
```

In `src/main.js` I need to get the path of the `worker` entry point relative to the output folder, e.g. `./worker.123456.js`.

Consider the following use-case:

```js
/* hardcoded path, wont work in practice as the filename changes */
const worker = new Worker("./worker.123456.js");
```

Some things I've tried but not working:

```
// doesn't work, no module named worker
import worker from "worker";

// doesn't work, pulls a copy of non-transpiled file
import worker from "!!file-loader!./worker";
```

Haven't seen anything in the documentation about this but perhaps I'm just missing the right keyword.

How to I get the output filename of an entry point in another source file?

**EDIT**: changed `a` and `b` to `main` and `worker` for a better example.

Comment: If `a` depends on `b`, why are you building two separate bundles? It sounds like you have a single codebase, not two separate codebases.

Comment: Consider if `a` is trying to start a new [`Worker`] (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Worker) with `b` as the script. In my case it is a platform restriction out of my control where a proprietary API needs to dynamically fetch the script.

Comment: Then don't output a "chunk managed" script, but have a second webpack config for generating that `b` with a stable file name? Or, do a rename pass after this finishes so that `/dist/b.whatever.js` gets `mv`'d into `/dist/b.min.js` or something. And remember that you'll need to mark whatever does an `import` as a `<script src="..." type="module">`. Not module type, no import/export.

Comment: Ok, so it basically boils down to "no, webpack cannot do that"? If that is the case I can think of multiple workarounds but it's a shame if it cannot be solved directly with webpack. As for now I'm using `html-webpack-plugin` to write the path to a global variable and then access that global when I need the path but it's quite an ugly solution.

Comment: Effectively. But this problem is primarily caused by opting for constantly changing names: if you don't actually need that, because your server is properly configured to return 304 for unchanged builds and true 200 with new data for changed builds, then aside from literal chunking (e.g. splitting your code up into multiple files for progressive loading) then there's no reason to use it, and this problem would go away without needing any hacks.

Comment: Need it for cache-busting on an enterprise platform which will rewrite the url to `/content?filename=my/path/to/file.js` and it caches way to aggresively and it is out of my control. Using immutable assets with changing names is the only way. The very same platform is also the reason I need to fetch the file dynamically instead of just a vanilla `<script>` tag. Client wont change platform but it isn't suitable for the modern web.

Comment: Sorry to hear it - good luck =(

Comment: @ext did you find a better answer to this? Perhaps with Webpack 5?

I'm trying to do something similar - separate entry point for the worker script

Comment: @eddiewould sorry no, I ended up hardcoding the path and using `?timestamp=${buildTime}` as cache buster. Haven't investigated further into webpack 5.